# Prepare statement - limit results by timestamp

Tags: php

I want to limit the SQL results to older than 1 week.

Here's how it looks in an usual SQL-query which is not prepared:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM `table_name` 
  WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
  ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC"
```

But as I am using PDO and I prepare all the queries, I tried to do this:

```
    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :time DAY) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC');
    $query->bindValue(':time', 7, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
```

But nothing happened.
I usually manage to get everything right, but this one was a little tricky. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Nothing happened? Not even an error?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to prepare constants or anything else that you know is clean. Just run the query as usual.

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC');
$query->execute();
```

Although your original method should have worked as well - are you sure there are records in the database that are older than 7 days?

Comment: Oh, damn.. well I've been coding all day, I did not notice that I also had prepared a limit in the query - hence I couldn't get what I wanted.. heh, thanks anyway!